# In javascript is there a way to preserve object "privacy" against Object.keys

Tags: javascript

With Object.keys method you can inspect all object properties, let's say you create an sdk and want to hide some internal properties, how to prevent Object.keys to get access to all properties somehow ?

Comment: Make them non-enumerable? Use private fields?

Comment: Yes as @VLAZ mentions check [private instance fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)

Comment: FWIW, pretty much anything will be inspectable via a debugger. While you may be able to prevent *programmatic* access, you can't completely *hide* anything in code running on the user's very own machine.